# How to prove $\int_0^1x\ln^2(1+x)\ln(\frac{x^2}{1+x})\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

How to prove
$$\int_0^1x\ln^2(1+x)\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=-\frac{7}{32}\cdot\zeta{(3)}\ln2+\frac{3\pi^2}{128}\cdot\ln^22-\frac{1}{64}\cdot\ln^42-\frac{13\pi^4}{46080}$$
The substitution $$x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$$ leads to calculate the integrals that are unknown:
$$\int_0^1y\ln(1-y)\ln^2(1+y)\frac{dy}{1+y^2}, \int_0^1\frac{y\ln^3(1+y)}{1+y^2}dy$$
For the moment,I do not see how to calculate this integral.

Comment: Hi! Where did you found this integral?

Comment: $$\ln\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x+1}\bigg)=\ln(x^2)-\ln(1+x)=2\ln(x)-\ln(1+x)$$ don't know if that helps

Comment: Do any of you know the Maclaurin series for $\ln^2(1+x)$? Maybe we can solve it  this way.

Comment: This integral has been proposed to me by friend.

Comment: Here is an ideea, we have: $$a^2 b=\frac16\left((a+b)^3-(a-b)^3-2b^3\right)$$
Thus the integral is equal to: $$I=2\cdot \frac16\left( \int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx+ \int_0^1\frac{x\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}dx -2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^3(1-x)}{1+x^2}\right)-\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^3(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
Thus let $x^2=t$ for the first one and $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t$ for the second one and try to simplify some. This way we don't have any product between the logarithms.

Comment: @Zacky If it helps, making the substitutions $x\to -\frac{x}{1+x}$ and $x\to \frac{x-1}{2}$ shows that the integral in question is equal to
$$\int_0^1 \ln^2\bigg(\frac{1+x}{2}\bigg)\ln\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1-x)^2}{1+x}\bigg)\frac{x-1}{x+1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$
Perhaps using your $a^2 b$ trick on this integral and combining it with the original representation can cause some sort of desirable cancellation to happen.

Comment: Do you want an insightful proof or what do you expect? It is actually not too difficult to proof by using polylog identities, but i'm not sure thats what you want.

Comment: @Diger: I will be glad to see your solution using polylog identities.

Comment: Anyway, the proposed integral is the sum of two integrals expressible by rational linear combination of the constants $\zeta(3)\ln 2,\zeta(4),\pi^2\ln^2 2,\ln^4 2,\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and the terms in $\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ are cancelling each other. (i don't have a proof, lindep of PARI GP rulez !)

Comment: What is canceling each other precisely? Regarding the polylog stuff I won't be able to write it here until end of next week earliest, since I only have mobile phone until then and I can assure you it is not "beautiful" just ugly algebra.

Comment: What I find far more interesting is the fact that each term can be expressed as a multiple of $\log^n(2) \zeta(4-n)$ for $n=0,1,2,4$. It is like there is a unit which needs to be conserved as in an underlying structure.

Comment: Numerically,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{467}{256}\zeta(4)-\frac{5}{64}\ln^4 2+\frac{3}{32}\pi^2\ln^2 2-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{15}{8}\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\end{align}


\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^3(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{1881}{512}\zeta(4)-\frac{9}{64}\ln^4 2+\frac{21}{128}\pi^2\ln^2 2-\frac{105}{32}\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{15}{4}\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\end{align} the terms in $\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ are killing each other.

Comment: @FDP your relationships are checked by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Do you have we demonstrations?

Comment: @user178256: of course not (yet). Maybe these relations are harder to obtain than the one in the question. I have supposed these integrals are rational combination of the constants $\zeta(4),\pi^2,\ln^4 2,\pi^2 \ln^2,\zeta(3)\ln 2,\text{Li_4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $ and using GP PARI allow to guess if the supposition is right of not (but it's a proof of nothing for sure)

Comment: @zacky: I'm wondering how you obtained your result since I get $$\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{x^2+1} \log(x) \log^2(1+x) \, {\rm d}x \\ =\int_0^1 \frac{2(1-x)}{(1+x)(x^2+1)} \log\left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right) \log^2\left(\frac{2}{1+x}\right) \, {\rm d}x \, ,$$ different from the OP which you probably used.

Comment: @Diger You probably wanted to tag FDP, because I didn't obtain anything yet :D

Comment: i just meant your "thus the integral is equal to: I=...".

Comment: Oh, I just used $a^2 b=\frac16\left((a+b)^3-(a-b)^3-2b^3\right)$. Where $a=\ln(1+x)$ and $b=\ln(1-x)$. Wait, I think I did a big mistake since I had $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$

Comment: So instead of the above we would then have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{x^2+1} \log(x) \log^2(1+x) \, {\rm d}x \\ = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1+x}\frac{1}{x^2+1} \Bigg\{ \log^3\left( \frac{2(1-x)}{1+x} \right) - \log^3\left( \frac{2}{1-x^2} \right)  - 2\log^3\left(1-x \right) \\ - \log^3(2) + \log^3\left( \frac{2}{(1+x)^2} \right) + 2\log^3\left( 1+x \right) \Bigg\} \, {\rm d}x \, ,
$$
of which only the second one $(\log^3\left( \frac{2}{1-x^2} \right))$ seems to be lacking an anti-derivative.

Comment: Just curios: Have you tried to use Mathematica to find an anti-derivative?

Answer (score 5):

Note that:
$$\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=\frac{1}{2}\ln ^4\left(2\right)-\frac{3}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$

Now I'll evaluate that integral in large steps.
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$=\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-2x+2x^2\right)}{x}\:dx-2\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(x\right)}{x}\:dx$$
$$=2\operatorname{\mathfrak{R}} \left\{\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(x\right)\ln \left(1-\left(1+i\right)x\right)}{x}\:dx\right\}+\frac{1}{2}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$
$$=-2\operatorname{\mathfrak{R}} \left\{-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(1+i\right)-2\ln \left(2\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)-\ln ^2\left(2\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)\right\}$$
$$+\frac{1}{2}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$
The real part of these polylogarithm are well-known, using their closed-form yields:
$$\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$=-\frac{627}{256}\zeta \left(4\right)+\frac{5}{2}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{35}{16}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{21}{32}\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{41}{96}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$
Replacing this into the first line yields the closed-form for that other integral.
$$\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\frac{1881}{512}\zeta \left(4\right)-\frac{15}{4}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{105}{32}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(3\right)+\frac{63}{64}\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-\frac{9}{64}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$

---

Now for your next integral:
$$\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(1-x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx+\frac{1}{6}\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx-\frac{1}{3}\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(1-x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(1-x\right)}{1+x}dx+\frac{1}{6}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(x\right)}{1+x}\:dx-\frac{1}{6}\int _0^1\frac{x\ln ^3\left(x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$-\frac{1}{3}\operatorname{\mathfrak{R}} \left\{\frac{1-i}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^3\left(x\right)}{1-\frac{1-i}{2}x}\:dx\right\}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{105}{128}\zeta \left(4\right)+2\operatorname{\mathfrak{R}} \left\{\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)\right\}$$
Thus:
$$\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=-\frac{77}{512}\zeta \left(4\right)+\frac{1}{8}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{5}{64}\ln ^2\left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{48}\ln ^4\left(2\right)$$

Comment: Hi Jorge!  The result of the integral is proposed [here](https://m.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2881251138871344&id=100009594579126&set=gm.2744105499047045&source=48&refid=18&_ft_=qid.6977422553926704060%3Amf_story_key.2744105499047045%3Atop_level_post_id.2744105499047045%3Atl_objid.2744105499047045%3Acontent_owner_id_new.100009594579126%3Apage_id.355300697927549%3Asrc.22%3Astory_location.6%3Astory_attachment_style.photo%3Afilter.GroupStoriesByActivityEntQuery%3Atds_flgs.3%3Aott.AX_un3hw-fc6v4EG&__tn__=EH-R). I even shared in harmonic group. Unfortunately,  I mistakenly deleted.

Comment: @Jorge Layja wondeful results, very good(+1)